# Android app crashes when converting JSON using Gson and getting response with Volley

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gson, android-volley

My app crashes whenever I try to get a location using the google places api. I'm using Volley to get a response from the URL and then using Gson to convert the JSON data.

I am getting a response from the URL however, I can't seem to figure out how to convert the JSON into usable text. Here I am trying to get the latitude of the place but the app crashes.

```
        btRestaurant.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
                String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=52.573012,-1.173310&radius=500&type=restaurant&key=KEY";

                // Request a string response from the provided URL.
                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                Gson gson = new Gson();
                                Result result = gson.fromJson(response, Result.class);
                                Log.i("AJB", String.valueOf(result.getGeometry().getLocation().getLat()));


                            }
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error occured", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });


                // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
                queue.add(stringRequest);
            }
        });
```

Here are the POJOS

```
public class Result {

    @SerializedName("business_status")
    @Expose
    private String businessStatus;
    @SerializedName("geometry")
    @Expose
    private Geometry geometry;
    @SerializedName("icon")
    @Expose
    private String icon;
    @SerializedName("icon_background_color")
    @Expose
    private String iconBackgroundColor;
    @SerializedName("icon_mask_base_uri")
    @Expose
    private String iconMaskBaseUri;
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("opening_hours")
    @Expose
    private OpeningHours openingHours;
    @SerializedName("photos")
    @Expose
    private List<Photo> photos = null;
    @SerializedName("place_id")
    @Expose
    private String placeId;
    @SerializedName("plus_code")
    @Expose
    private PlusCode plusCode;
    @SerializedName("price_level")
    @Expose
    private Integer priceLevel;
    @SerializedName("rating")
    @Expose
    private Integer rating;
    @SerializedName("reference")
    @Expose
    private String reference;
    @SerializedName("scope")
    @Expose
    private String scope;
    @SerializedName("types")
    @Expose
    private List<String> types = null;
    @SerializedName("user_ratings_total")
    @Expose
    private Integer userRatingsTotal;
    @SerializedName("vicinity")
    @Expose
    private String vicinity;

    public String getBusinessStatus() {
        return businessStatus;
    }

    public void setBusinessStatus(String businessStatus) {
        this.businessStatus = businessStatus;
    }

    public Geometry getGeometry() {
        return geometry;
    }

    public void setGeometry(Geometry geometry) {
        this.geometry = geometry;
    }

    public String getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }

    public void setIcon(String icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    public String getIconBackgroundColor() {
        return iconBackgroundColor;
    }

    public void setIconBackgroundColor(String iconBackgroundColor) {
        this.iconBackgroundColor = iconBackgroundColor;
    }

    public String getIconMaskBaseUri() {
        return iconMaskBaseUri;
    }

    public void setIconMaskBaseUri(String iconMaskBaseUri) {
        this.iconMaskBaseUri = iconMaskBaseUri;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public OpeningHours getOpeningHours() {
        return openingHours;
    }

    public void setOpeningHours(OpeningHours openingHours) {
        this.openingHours = openingHours;
    }

    public List<Photo> getPhotos() {
        return photos;
    }

    public void setPhotos(List<Photo> photos) {
        this.photos = photos;
    }

    public String getPlaceId() {
        return placeId;
    }

    public void setPlaceId(String placeId) {
        this.placeId = placeId;
    }

    public PlusCode getPlusCode() {
        return plusCode;
    }

    public void setPlusCode(PlusCode plusCode) {
        this.plusCode = plusCode;
    }

    public Integer getPriceLevel() {
        return priceLevel;
    }

    public void setPriceLevel(Integer priceLevel) {
        this.priceLevel = priceLevel;
    }

    public Integer getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    public void setRating(Integer rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    public String getReference() {
        return reference;
    }

    public void setReference(String reference) {
        this.reference = reference;
    }

    public String getScope() {
        return scope;
    }

    public void setScope(String scope) {
        this.scope = scope;
    }

    public List<String> getTypes() {
        return types;
    }

    public void setTypes(List<String> types) {
        this.types = types;
    }

    public Integer getUserRatingsTotal() {
        return userRatingsTotal;
    }

    public void setUserRatingsTotal(Integer userRatingsTotal) {
        this.userRatingsTotal = userRatingsTotal;
    }

    public String getVicinity() {
        return vicinity;
    }

    public void setVicinity(String vicinity) {
        this.vicinity = vicinity;
    }

}
```

```
public class Geometry {

    @SerializedName("location")
    @Expose
    private Location location;
    @SerializedName("viewport")
    @Expose
    private Viewport viewport;

    public Location getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(Location location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public Viewport getViewport() {
        return viewport;
    }

    public void setViewport(Viewport viewport) {
        this.viewport = viewport;
    }

}
```

```
public class Location {

    @SerializedName("lat")
    @Expose
    private Double lat;
    @SerializedName("lng")
    @Expose
    private Double lng;

    public Double getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public void setLat(Double lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }

    public Double getLng() {
        return lng;
    }

    public void setLng(Double lng) {
        this.lng = lng;
    }

}
```

Crash log

```
2023-01-04 17:56:35.951 14801-14801/aston.cs3mdd.pubgolf E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: aston.cs3mdd.pubgolf, PID: 14801
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'aston.cs3mdd.pubgolf.ui.dashboard.Location aston.cs3mdd.pubgolf.ui.dashboard.Geometry.getLocation()' on a null object reference
        at aston.cs3mdd.pubgolf.ui.dashboard.DashboardFragment$3$1.onResponse(DashboardFragment.java:184)
        at aston.cs3mdd.pubgolf.ui.dashboard.DashboardFragment$3$1.onResponse(DashboardFragment.java:173)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:82)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:29)
        at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:102)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
```

**SOLUTION**

The right way to get data is to use `result.getResults().get(index).getLocation().getLat()`

Comment: I'll suggest you also show the crash log

Comment: @Jayhymn Added the crash log

Comment: I haven't seen anything wrong but if you're sure you're getting the expected response from the api and the response is in the correct format but it still isn't working, parse the response using JsonParser before deserializing it to the specified class. What I mean is do this instead; Result result = gson.fromJson(JsonParser().parse(response), Result.class)

Comment: @Jayhymn I've tried your suggestion, but it's still giving the same error. I think the problem is somewhere in the POJOs? since that's when the data returns as null.

Comment: Does the JSON in the toast message look correct? (or maybe also switch that to propper logging for now to make troubleshooting easier) Please also log `gson.toJson(result)` (or set a breakpoint) to see if Gson parsed any of the fields successfully. Note that Gson does not fail for missing or unknown fields in JSON.

Comment: The problem was caused because I wasn't using the right POJOS, it was missing some classes. The right way to get the data was to use "result.getResults().get(index).getLocation().getLat()". I'll update the post for future people needing this.